# What could be the replacement for [MoveCommand] in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

I'm learning iOS development and was watching a tutorial on YouTube which is very old from 2014.

```
import UIKit

protocol GameModelProtocol: class {
    func scoreChange(score: Int)
    func moveOneTile(from: (Int, Int), to: (Int, Int), value: Int)
    func moveTwoTile(from: ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)), to: (Int, Int), value: Int)
    func insertTile(location: (Int, Int), value: Int)
}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
class GameModel: NSObject {

let dim: Int
let limit: Int

var score: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        delegate.scoreChange(score: score)
    }
}

var gameBoard: SquareGameBoard<TileObject>

let delegate: GameModelProtocol

var queue: [MoveCommand]

var timer: Timer

let maxCommands = 100
let queueDelay = 0.3

init(dim d: Int, limit l: Int, delegate: GameModelProtocol) {
    dim = d
    limit = l
    self.delegate = delegate
    queue = [MoveCommand]()
    timer = Timer()
    gameBoard = SquareGameBoard(dim: d, initialValue: .Empty)
    super.init()
}
```

The instructor said that he was using it as an array. But I couldn't figure out how it was being used or how I could change it to work with Swift 4.

Here's the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTBeiNpymhs&list=PLY1aWv2j4oDH5eua91og5kySNULnSt0SU&index=7&t=0s) to the YouTube video.

I just wanna know how [MoveCommand] can be replaced to work in Swift 4. I've fixed most of the issues in the code but this one I can't figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MoveCommand is a struct which is Defined in AuxiliaryModels.swift. You should download the full project sample code: https://github.com/austinzheng/swift-2048
Hope this helps.